# Get total_rows from couchbase ruby library

Tags: ruby, couchbase, couchbase-view

When having a look to my couchbase view using the web api I got this result:

```
{
  "total_rows": 18279385,
  "rows": []
}
```

But I'm using the ruby couchbase gem like follows

```
require 'couchbase'
c = Couchbase.connect(...)
sources = c.design_docs['Data']
pp sources.All
#<Couchbase::View:47373151271840 @endpoint="_design/Data/_view/All" @params={:connection_timeout=>75000}>
```

But how do I get the total_rows from the view? I've found few documentation which relates to a Method "total_rows" but that doesn't seem to be present at this point.

Comment: reading the docs, looks like you need use to `fetch` without a block to get access to `total_rows`.  can you try `sources.All.fetch` and tell me what that returns?

Comment: yes, @Anthony is right, the view have to be executed to get total_rows

Comment: @Anthony that solves the Problem.

Answer (score 0):

The comment of Anthony solves the problem:

```
sources.All(limit: 0).fetch.total_rows
```

Use limit: 0 for speeding up the request.